How can I CROSS JOIN but limit dates on a unit-subunit basis?
I have inventory information for various warehouses for various items. The first available date of each each item varies by warehouse. I'd like to compute average seven-day inventories for each warehouse, but only starting when an item first enters the inventory at that warehouse. If, however, the inventory goes to zero, I'd like to keep that in the data until the present.

How do I limit the starting dates on a warehouse-item basis?
Is there a faster way than the CROSS JOIN I use below?

I am using Starburst SQL.
Sample data
CREATE TABLE inventory (
    warehouse varchar(2),
    invdate date,
    item varchar(16),
    deltainventory real,
    inventory real
);

INSERT INTO inventory VALUES ('A', date'2020-01-01', 'item123', 1000, 1000);
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES ('A', date'2020-01-08', 'item123', -200, 800);
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES ('A', date'2020-01-13', 'item123', 500, 1300);
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES ('A', date'2020-01-19', 'item123', -800, 500);
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES ('B', date'2020-07-01', 'item789', 250, 250);
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES ('B', date'2020-07-09', 'item789', -250, 0);
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES ('B', date'2020-07-15', 'item789', 1000, 1000);
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES ('B', date'2020-07-31', 'item789', -400, 600);

Note that the table datelist is given at the bottom to avoid clutter.
CREATE TABLE inventoryfull AS 
SELECT  warehouse, item, invdate, deltainventory, inventory, 
        avg(COALESCE(inventory, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY (warehouse, item) ORDER BY invdate RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '7' DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS avg7 
FROM 
    (
    SELECT  l.warehouse, l.item, l.invdate,
            COALESCE(r.deltainventory, 0) AS deltainventory,
            sum(COALESCE(r.deltainventory, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY (l.warehouse, l.item) ORDER BY l.invdate RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS inventory
    FROM 
        (SELECT DISTINCT l0.warehouse, l0.item, r0.calendardate as invdate, CAST(NULL AS real) deltainventory
        FROM inventory AS l0 
        CROSS JOIN
            datelist as r0 -- list of calendar dates from opening of first warehouse to present, given at bottom to avoid clutter
        ) AS l 
    LEFT JOIN
        inventory AS r 
    ON  l.warehouse = r.warehouse
        AND l.item = r.item
        AND l.invdate = r.invdate
    )
;

Here is the desired output. Note, in particular, that the inventory for Warehouse B, Item item789 starts on 7/1/2020, even though the calendar dates start at 1/1/2020.
Warehouse   InvDate Item    DeltaInventory  Inventory   Avg7
A   1/1/2020    item123 1000    1000    1000.0
A   1/2/2020    item123 0   1000    1000.0
A   1/3/2020    item123 0   1000    1000.0
A   1/4/2020    item123 0   1000    1000.0
A   1/5/2020    item123 0   1000    1000.0
A   1/6/2020    item123 0   1000    1000.0
A   1/7/2020    item123 0   1000    1000.0
A   1/8/2020    item123 -200    800 971.4
A   1/9/2020    item123 0   800 942.9
A   1/10/2020   item123 0   800 914.3
A   1/11/2020   item123 0   800 885.7
A   1/12/2020   item123 0   800 857.1
A   1/13/2020   item123 500 1300    900.0
A   1/14/2020   item123 0   1300    942.9
A   1/15/2020   item123 0   1300    1014.3
A   1/16/2020   item123 0   1300    1085.7
A   1/17/2020   item123 0   1300    1157.1
A   1/18/2020   item123 0   1300    1228.6
A   1/19/2020   item123 -800    500 1185.7
A   1/20/2020   item123 0   500 1071.4
A   1/21/2020   item123 0   500 957.1
A   1/22/2020   item123 0   500 842.9
A   1/23/2020   item123 0   500 728.6
A   1/24/2020   item123 0   500 614.3
A   1/25/2020   item123 0   500 500.0
A   1/26/2020   item123 0   500 500.0
A   1/27/2020   item123 0   500 500.0
A   1/28/2020   item123 0   500 500.0
...
A   7/31/2020   item123 0   500 500.0

B   7/1/2020    item789 250 250 250
B   7/2/2020    item789 0   250 250
B   7/3/2020    item789 0   250 250
B   7/4/2020    item789 0   250 250
B   7/5/2020    item789 0   250 250
B   7/6/2020    item789 0   250 250
B   7/7/2020    item789 0   250 250
B   7/8/2020    item789 0   250 250
B   7/9/2020    item789 -250    0   214.2857143
B   7/10/2020   item789 0   0   178.5714286
B   7/11/2020   item789 0   0   142.8571429
B   7/12/2020   item789 0   0   107.1428571
B   7/13/2020   item789 0   0   71.42857143
B   7/14/2020   item789 0   0   35.71428571
B   7/15/2020   item789 1000    1000    142.8571429
B   7/16/2020   item789 0   1000    285.7142857
B   7/17/2020   item789 0   1000    428.5714286
B   7/18/2020   item789 0   1000    571.4285714
B   7/19/2020   item789 0   1000    714.2857143
B   7/20/2020   item789 0   1000    857.1428571
B   7/21/2020   item789 0   1000    1000
B   7/22/2020   item789 0   1000    1000
B   7/23/2020   item789 0   1000    1000
B   7/24/2020   item789 0   1000    1000
B   7/25/2020   item789 0   1000    1000
B   7/26/2020   item789 0   1000    1000
B   7/27/2020   item789 0   1000    1000
B   7/28/2020   item789 0   1000    1000
B   7/29/2020   item789 0   1000    1000
B   7/30/2020   item789 0   1000    1000
B   7/31/2020   item789 -400    600 942.8571429


I tried the code above plus the additional ON condition l.invdate >= min(r.invdate) OVER (PARTITION BY (r.warehouse, r.item)), but I get an error stating that a "JOIN clause cannot contain aggregations, window functions, or grouping operations."
Here is the datelist table.
CREATE TABLE datelist (
    calendardate date
);
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-01');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-02');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-03');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-04');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-05');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-06');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-07');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-08');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-09');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-10');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-11');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-12');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-13');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-14');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-15');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-16');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-17');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-18');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-19');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-20');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-21');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-22');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-23');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-24');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-25');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-26');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-27');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-28');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-29');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-30');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-01-31');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-01');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-02');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-03');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-04');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-05');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-06');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-07');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-08');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-09');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-10');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-11');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-12');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-13');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-14');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-15');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-16');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-17');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-18');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-19');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-20');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-21');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-22');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-23');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-24');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-25');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-26');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-27');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-28');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-02-29');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-01');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-02');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-03');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-04');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-05');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-06');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-07');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-08');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-09');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-10');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-11');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-12');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-13');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-14');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-15');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-16');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-17');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-18');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-19');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-20');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-21');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-22');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-23');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-24');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-25');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-26');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-27');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-28');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-29');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-30');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-03-31');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-01');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-02');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-03');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-04');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-05');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-06');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-07');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-08');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-09');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-10');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-11');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-12');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-13');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-14');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-15');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-16');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-17');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-18');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-19');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-20');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-21');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-22');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-23');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-24');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-25');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-26');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-27');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-28');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-29');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-04-30');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-01');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-02');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-03');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-04');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-05');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-06');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-07');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-08');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-09');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-10');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-11');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-12');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-13');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-14');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-15');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-16');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-17');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-18');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-19');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-20');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-21');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-22');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-23');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-24');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-25');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-26');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-27');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-28');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-29');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-30');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-05-31');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-01');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-02');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-03');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-04');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-05');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-06');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-07');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-08');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-09');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-10');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-11');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-12');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-13');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-14');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-15');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-16');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-17');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-18');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-19');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-20');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-21');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-22');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-23');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-24');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-25');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-26');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-27');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-28');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-29');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-06-30');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-01');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-02');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-03');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-04');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-05');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-06');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-07');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-08');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-09');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-10');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-11');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-12');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-13');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-14');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-15');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-16');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-17');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-18');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-19');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-20');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-21');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-22');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-23');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-24');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-25');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-26');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-27');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-28');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-29');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-30');
INSERT INTO datelist VALUES (date'2020-07-31');


You upload your full db ....

from (select warehouse, item, min(invdate) as startdate from inventory group by warehouse, item) as l inner join datelist d on d.calendardate >= l.startdate ...
